# What is the word for dragging motion of a finger on a trackpad?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the appropriate word for the dragging motion of a finger on a trackpad of a laptop or any surface with an intention to make an effect?

Comment: caress, stroke?

Comment: can't agree @Jon

Comment: I only checked because I had never heard that component being called a *track pad* before. I thought maybe it's American or Australian or something. But I only found [**touch pad**](http://software.isrg.org.uk/vipi/downloadedcourse/resources/10.html)

Comment: @Mari-LouA http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ2R2LL/A/magic-trackpad-2

Comment: OK I think it's an Apple thing http://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/macbook/the-parts-of-your-macbook/ first time I've ever heard a touchpad being called a track.

Comment: @neckTwi I agree that 'caress' is not applicable, but I can't see what's wrong with 'stroke'. After all we make 'strokes' with pens, pencils and brushes when writing. I know that's a noun and you're looking for a verb but 'stroke' seems fine to me.

Comment: We're getting on the verge of technical language versus English Language and Usage.  Does question belong somewhere else?

Comment: Isn't 'gesture' what Apple use for the movements you make on a touch-screen/trackpad, the swipe, pinch and un-pinch gestures, for instance?

Comment: @Xanne can you imagine any natural thing that responds to the finger touch gesture?

Comment: @Xanne El&U accepts technical language questions, as long as they are recognised/established  words. Neologisms are generally frowned upon.

Comment: @BoldBen `stroke` seems to be is more apt than `swipe` but I feel they are more intending the effect of the action than the action itself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "trackpad", I'm fairly sure, was actually the earlier term. And if I'm not mistaken you had "trackball" before that.  (If I'm not mistaken those were used in eg. military applications (for literally "tracking" things), just as joysticks of various forms existed ***before*** they were commonly thought of as "computer things").)  Anyway I do believe "trackpad" was the earlier name for the things on laptops, now "touchpad" is more common? Note that they won't exist within a couple years, simply "that area of the laptop case" will entirely be touch sensitive - know what I mean?

Comment: @Fattie Trackballs are still a thing, I use one. Like the track pad, the way it works means you only need to move your fingers to move the cursor, not the rest of your arm like a conventional mouse.

Comment: "Trackballs are still a thing, I use one" right, a handful of specialists use one.  My point to Marilou was just that "trackpad" actually came before "touchpad", perhaps surprisingly today.

Comment: @Fattie It's not just specialists - lots of people use trackballs because they are supposed to be lower risk than normal mice for RSI/CTS. Personally, I use them just because I got used to them and find them nicer for a mix of precise mouse movement and large movements.

Comment: the inevitable [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/243/)

Comment: There is no single answer to this question, because we normally don't talk about the physical interaction with the touchpad separately from the onscreen effect which results. And, there may be many different onscreen effects: Drag, point, swipe, pinch, and many other kinds of multi-touch possibilities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Slide* is an alternative to move used in, e.g., the following description of possible gestures on a trackpad:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895

Comment: it said slide with two fingers, so I can't agree

Comment: @neckTwi The verb will remain the same no matter how many fingers you need to use for a specific gesture. [This article](https://help.blackberry.com/en/blackberry-classic/10.3.1/help/mes1335535802053.html) for example describes sliding gestures with just one finger. I think it is a good answer, and I'm a software engineer.

Comment: "Slide" and "move" (also "tap") are verbs for what your finger or fingers do on the trackpad or touch pad; other verbs describe what you want to accomplish on the screen--zoom, rotate, scroll, drag and drop. What the more complex gestures do can often be edited by the user.

Comment: @undercat do you say "slide trackpad with two fingers" or "slide two fingers on trackpad"?

Comment: I prefer drag to slide

Comment: @neckTwi - Drag is definitely the correct term _if_ the touchpad or a button is held down at the same time, but only then. "Drag" is often used along with "drop", e.g. "Drag a file out of one folder and drop it in another." If you called it "drag" when a button or the pad is _not_ pressed down, it would be confusing.

Comment: I can't deny its definition though I have a bit different connotation for the word. I only thought of sliding down a slide until I have referred the dictionary.

Comment: this is utterly incorrect

Comment: ... in terms of how I understand the question.

Comment: Apple should never be used as the correct source for this unless the question is specifically about Apple products.  They frequently go against the grain

Comment: @USER_8675309 You mean they think different.

Comment: @thunderblaster They don't think different -- they want money just like every other company.  Their way of doing it is attempting to be unique

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be [a joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_different).

Comment: This is the best answer. "Slide to unlock"

Comment: @mbomb007 but for "Slide to unlock" isn't there a thing displayed there, and one must *slide the thing* to unlock? They don't say "swipe right anywhere to unlock".

Answer (score 47):

The verb you need here is ***swipe***. Unlike the verb *slide*, the word *swipe* gives an indication of a sudden  and swift movement. Here is an explanation of *swiping* from [Tech Terms](https://techterms.com/definition/swipe):

> > Swipe is a command used primarily with touchscreen devices, such as smartphones and tablets. It is also supported by some laptops with trackpads and desktop computers with trackpad input.
> >
> > A swipe involves quickly moving (or "swiping") your finger across a touchscreen or trackpad. For example, swiping the screen from right to left in a photo viewing application typically displays the next photo. While browsing multiple photos, swiping up or down may allow you scroll through the photo library. Most smartphones also allow you to swipe left or right to switch between home screens.
> >
> > Devices that support multi-touch may allow you to swipe with multiple fingers to perform different functions. For example, MacBook users can swipe left or right with two fingers to perform the Back or Forward command in a web browser. Swiping up or down with three fingers performs the Exposé command in Mac OS X.

---

<sup>**Reference:** Christensson, Per. "Swipe Definition." TechTerms. (June 21, 2012). Accessed Apr 6, 2017. https://techterms.com/definition/swipe.</sup>

Comment: The only correct answer.  "Drag" is also perfectly correct, *if you are dragging something*.  (So, when "moving a file icon" or during "drag and drop" operations.)  With two fingers, it is usually a "pinch".

Comment: `slide: move smoothly along a surface while maintaining continuous contact with it` is not apt because it is `along a surface` but not `on the surface`? @Fattie

Comment: Actually it's not that correct  :)  Also the reference writers are hopeless ("quickly" has no connection, whatsoever, to swiping: you can swipe as slowly as you happen to want to).

Comment: "Swipe" is only accurate when your motion results in windows or screens being swiped out of the way. Swipe is the name of one of the many possible interaction which might result from the physical motion. You don't call it swiping when you're dragging, and you don't call it swiping when all you're doing is moving the pointer.

Comment: This answer is for a specific type of motion, so I think that *slide* is better, because it encompasses more types of motion. A swipe is always a single, sudden motion. If you wanted to describe a circular motion on the trackpack, it would make more sense to say "slide your finger in a circle" than "swipe your finger in a circle". Same with "slide to unlock."

Comment: @neckTwi It's got nothing to do with the *dictionary* definition - clearly a *swipe* gesture is perfectly described by the word "slide", it's just *not idiomatic* in the context of user interface input on a trackpad device.

Comment: @Beanluc That is not true. Windows or screens being swiped out of the way is not an integral part of what swiping is. Many touch-enabled devices/OSes can be unlocked by swiping in a particular direction, for example, without anything being swiped anywhere. What is true is that swiping is a single, fast(ish) motion, unlike dragging or sliding, which can be slower and comprise multiple directions.

Comment: Now you can swipe without even touching the screen.

Comment: @Fattie you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Brush (v):

> As she brushed her finger across the touchpad, the mouse cursor followed her motion.

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited the question to better reflect my intentions

Comment: ＋１  a nice word; “brushing along” quite matches the actual action, but it is to be determined if it’s suitable regarding touch screens (along with “swipe”, “pinch”, “tap”, etc.).

Comment: Swipe is rather good, @dakab, it's got a speedier connotation. OK if I include it to make the answer more complete?

Comment: Yeah swipe is the first word I got but after looking it up in the dictionary it seems bit heavy

Comment: "Swipe" (in various directions, with one or more fingers) is something you can do, but it usually does more than move the cursor on the screen--it will may go to another page of a document or a different application that's open.

Comment: This would be a good literary description, but it's never used as a word for the thing being discussed.

Comment: Nobody ever uses the word "brush" to describe an interaction with a touch-based computer control device.

Answer (score 3):

This information is a little domain-specific (electronic devices), but JavaFX and Android libraries have names for user interactions like you've described.

[JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)

1. TouchMoved - means that a user has touched the screen and then moved their finger without lifting it off the screen
2. Swipe[Direction(Down,Left,Right,Up)] - means that a user has touched the screen and then moved their finger in a single motion that approached the edge of the screen/application

[Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) refers to any user touch interaction as an 'onTouch' in general. The actual motion will be a motion event, specifically an 'ACTION_MOVE'as described a few pages down [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html). (It's called a 'HOVER_MOVE' if the user isn't actually touching the screen.) A motion event which intersects with an edge of the screen is an 'Edge[Direction(Bottom,Left,Top,Right)]', which seems to closely match the JavaFX concept of Swipe.

From this, I believe that the word you are looking for is a 'touch move'.

I would not say 'swipe' unless you are implying that the user has dragged their finger/tool to an edge. I would be careful with 'slide', since that implies a linear motion and the word doesn't even appear in the Android MotionEvent or the JavaFX Node documentation.

Comment: As you mention, those terms are specific to the codes you're describing but you're completely accurate that *swipe* and *slide* are not the correct answers here.

Answer (score 3):

I do believe [***swipe***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=swipe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cswipe%3B%2Cc0) to be the most correct term and reckon it has or will soon be the de facto recognized nomenclature for the dragging motion of a finger [on a trackpad].

The term [***scroll***](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20scroll) also has some application, meaning: "move displayed text or graphics in a particular direction on a computer screen in order to view different parts of them."

Where *swipe* tends to imply decisive action, *scroll* does not.

Comment: As above, *swipe* is only correct where the action moves windows &c. out of the way; *dragging* items around the screen is distinguished; *scrolling* up and down is distinguished; *moving the pointer* isn't included in any of them.

Comment: I would disagree that *swipe* is only correct where the action is moving windows out of the way -- even though it is the more accurate term for that specific action.  The usage is increasingly generic for "dragging motion of a finger on a trackpad" and I would maintain that the word is appropriate.

Comment: I simply don't believe you that anyone says 'I swiped the cursor around' or 'I moved the icon by swiping it'. As you say, maybe in the future.

Comment: Now that you mention it my reference might be more focused on *touchpanel* rather than *trackpad* - since you mention cursors.  I can't imagine swiping a cursor!  This is post-cursor talk.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is a distinct clue in the name 'trackpad', as your finger could be said to *track* across the pad.

Miriam-Webster's definition of [track](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/track) as a transitive verb, definition 3:

> to travel over :  **traverse**,  *track* a desert

And for example:

> She *tracked* her finger over the pad.

See also [trace](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trace).

Comment: This would be a good literary description, but it's never used as a word for the thing being discussed.

Comment: The pad tracks the *finger's* movement across it; the finger isn't tracking anything. (Yes, there's a tertiary sense of the word that could mean that. The fact remains that that is not what was intended or is understood by the term in this context.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single generic phrase for "the dragging motion of a finger on a trackpad" as there are multiple gestures with different effects. There are also gestures which only involve touching or pressing the pad without moving the finger on it, so *gesture* would be wider.

The most common gesture is *tracking* - the effect of moving the mouse pointer by 'pushing' it by one or more drags. The position is relative and the motion accelerates slightly based on the speed of the gesture. This different to how a touch tablet works - a tablet is absolute so interprets the position of the gesture as the scaled position of the pointer, whereas a trackpad keeps track of the mouse pointer and adds the effect of the gesture to that position. It's so common a gesture that it almost never gets mentioned, except of course in the name of the device.

You can *swipe* if the motion is to move a window, show the Windows Charms, accept or reject an option, or go back. Swipes usually ignore gestures which are too slow.

You can *drag* by selecting something in an application then touch and hold and drag your fingers.

You can *scroll* by dragging two fingers at once in the same direction.

You can *pinch* by dragging two fingers towards or [away from each other](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177077/does-pinch-have-an-opposite).

There are other gestures, but there isn't a generic word for 'gestures which involve movement'.

Comment: But the *device* is the one *tracking* the motion of the user's fingertip. The motion of the fingertip itself is not *tracking*. Still you're much more correct than the more upvoted posts in pointing out that we use a horde of different terms depending on the action being taken.